# Creating border on hover with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to get this code working all morning to absolutely no avail. I know I'm just doing something simple wrong but I just can't figure it out?

Would any of you guys be able to give me a hand?

I'm trying to make a white bottom border show up when you over over the link in the navigation. The page that you are currently on will be displayed green so the border for that link needs to be green on hover instead of white.

http://jsfiddle.net/sCt7r/

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("hoverEffect").hover(
            function() { $(this).addClass("Hover1"); },
            function() { $(this).removeClass("Hover1"); }
            );
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".navSelect").hover(
            function() { $(this).addClass("Hover2"); },
            function() { $(this).removeClass("Hover2");}
            );
        });
```

Comment: Why not just `.navigation a:hover { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some changes:

1) You're missing jQuery in your fiddle

2) You just need one DOM ready handler `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

3) Use `.` to target class , so use `$(".hoverEffect")` instead of `$("hoverEffect")`

4) You need to add class `hover1` and `hover2` not `Hover1` and `Hover2`

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sCt7r/6/)**

But actually you can use pure CSS to achieve this task using `:hover` selector:

```
.hoverEffect:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.navSelect:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sCt7r/4/)**

Comment: better to use **CSS** for hover :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery. Just use [CSS `:hover`].(https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

```
.navigation a.hoverEffect:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.navSelect:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

↪ [You can see this code in action at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sCt7r/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Several mistakes in your code go through the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $(".hoverEffect").on("mouseover", function(){
                $(this).addClass("hover1"); 

            });
$(".navSelect").on("mouseover", function(){
               $(this).addClass("hover2"); 
                $(this).removeClass("Hover2");
});
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sCt7r/17/

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes in the code, try this

http://jsfiddle.net/3LXH4/

but there is a also a simple way to do it using css, you can also try it..

Heres the code

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".hoverEffect").hover(
                function() { $(this).addClass("hover1"); },
                function() { $(this).removeClass("hover1"); }
            );

            $(".navSelect").hover(
                function() { $(this).addClass("hover2"); },
                function() { $(this).removeClass("hover2");}
            );
        });
```

Comment: Say if I wanted to have "Home" always have a bottom border. Upon hovering over any other link the border on home is removed and placed upon the hovered link.

I can just use the same code targeting a different class right?

Comment: you can do it using any dynamic language, check it its homepage set home link class as selected and underline it or use any other class you've already defined..make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".hoverEffect").on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover1");
});
$(".hoverEffect").on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover1");
});
```

in your code some mistakes:
its not Hover2, its hover2
$("hoverEffect").hover(.... must be $(".hoverEffect").hover(